# Access array of div elements via jquery to .show() or .hide() each one individually for carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, element

I'm creating a profiles page in javascript/jquery and I'm using a carousel of div's to accomplish said task. The question I have is, how do I programmatically access each style.display or $("#username").hide() or .show() ?

```js
function changeProfile(num) {
  var profiles = $('#profiles');
  if (num < 1) {
    index = 3;
  }
  if (num > 3) {
    index = 1;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    profiles[i].style.display = "none"; // error here
    // for example: $('#profiles')[0];  etc
  }
  profiles[index - 1].style.display = "block";
  console.log("Profile number: " + index);
}
```

```html
<div class="profiles">
  1 / 3
  <img src="images/blank1.jpg" style="width:90%">
</div>
<div class="profiles">
  2 / 3
  <img src="images/blank2.jpg" style="width:90%">
</div>
<div class="profiles">
  3 / 3
  <img src="images/blank.jpg" style="width:90%">
</div>
```

Comment: how does `changeProfile` gets called ?

Comment: changeProfile() gets called with a positive or negative 1, via buttons.

Comment: I see so did you resolve this by provided answers or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brother, you can try this. I saw you gave `profiles` as the class name but in the js you were searching as id. That's why the profiles[] were returning null.

```js
function changeProfile(num) {
    var profiles = $('.profiles');
    
    if (num < 1) {
        index = 3;
    }
    
    if (num > 3) {
        index = 1;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        profiles[i].style.display = "none"; // error here
    }
    
    profiles[num - 1].style.display = "block";
}

changeProfile(2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profiles">
   1 / 3
  <img src="https://neersyde.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/https___cdn.cnn_.com_cnnnext_dam_assets_190403144228-avengers-endgame-thumb-imax-poster-900x506.jpg" style="width:200px">
</div>
<div class="profiles">
  2 / 3
  <img src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/logan-and-x23-4k-2y.jpg" style="width:200px">
</div>
<div class="profiles">
  3 / 3
  <img src="https://akm-img-a-in.tosshub.com/sites/btmt/images/stories/avengers_endgame_660_050719024159.jpg" style="width:200px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use each function and then get the index of element to do something

https://api.jquery.com/each/

```js
function changeProfile(num) {
  $('.profiles').each(function(index, value) {
    if (num == index) {
      console.log('Get selected num: ' + num);
      $(this).fadeOut();
    } else {
      console.log(`div${index}: ${this.id}`);
    }
  });
}

changeProfile(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profiles">
    1 / 3
    <img src="images/blank1.jpg" style="width:90%">
</div>
<div class="profiles">
    2 / 3
    <img src="images/blank2.jpg" style="width:90%">
</div>
<div class="profiles">
    3 / 3
    <img src="images/blank.jpg" style="width:90%">
</div>
```